# aws eventbridge not creating ec2backsups with tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

i am unable to create a ec2 backups using event bridge with tags,even i mentioned tags in event bridge rules it is creating backups without tags,for that my ec2 life cycle policy manger unable to delete these backups without tags ,i am manually deleting these backups everyday, any ideas?

[image: aws eventbridge]

[image: aws eventbridge]

[image: lifecyclemaager ec2]

[image: lifecyclemaager ec2]

Answer (score 0):

The Tags you are configuring in the rule, apply only to the rule itself (the rule is tagged with those values) but not to the targets (in this case the new snapshot).

There are other ways to do that. You can use Lifecycle Manager or AWS Backup.

For Lifecycle Manager you need to specify the Target Resource Tags.

For AWS Backup, you additionally can also indicate specific resources (e.g. your EBS volume ID), add the tags you need and set and retention policy. So this service could be more suitable for your case.

---

Reference:

[Amazon EBS Integrates with AWS Backup](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/amazon-ebs-integrates-with-aws-backup-to-protect-your-volumes/)

Comment: thanks for ansewring i am trying what u said ,will update result in 2 days

Comment: Did you try that approach?